# Why is this not a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am wondering why $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x-1\rangle$ is not a field.

I understand why this wouldn't be a field in one respect:

We know $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x-1\rangle$$\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ using the evaluation ring homomorphism at $1$ and the first isomorphism theorem. So since $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x-1\rangle$ is isomorphic to a non-field, we get that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x-1\rangle$ is not a field.

But isn't $x-1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? Would this not then imply that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x-1\rangle$ is a field?

Comment: You may want to look up the theorem you are thinking of.

Comment: Being irreducible ensures that the product of two non-zero elements is not going to be zero. But the ideal can still be made larger without encompassing the whole ring. Therefore, there are going to still be elements that don't have inverse.

Comment: $\Bbb Z[x]/M$ is a field if and only if $M$ is a **maximal** ideal. In $\Bbb Z[x]$, maximal ideals are not just generated by irreducible polynomials.

Answer (score 4):

There is a related theorem you may be thinking of:  if $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal idea in a commutative ring $R$ (with $1$), then $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field.

**Proof**:  If $0\neq \overline{a}\in R/\mathfrak{m}$, then $\langle a,\mathfrak{m}\rangle$ is an ideal containing $\mathfrak{m}$.  Since $\mathfrak{m}$ is maximal, this implies $\langle a,\mathfrak{m}\rangle = R$, so there is a $b\in R$ with $1 = ab+m$ for some $m\in \mathfrak{m}$.  Then $\overline{a}\overline{b} = 1\in R/\mathfrak{m}$.$\square$

But note that in your case, $\langle x-1\rangle\subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is *not* maximal.  For example. $\langle x-1, 2\rangle$ is a proper ideal which strictly contains $\langle x-1\rangle$.

Comment: To OP: As a side note, do not that if you swap Z[x] for C[x], the Nullstellenstatz theorem would imply the <x-1> is a maximal ideal, then the quotient would be a field.

Answer (score 3):

The theorem is that, ${\bf{F}}[x]/(f(x))$ is a field if and only if $f(x)$ is irreducible, but the condition here is that ${\bf{F}}$ is a field.

Here ${\bf{Z}}$ is not a field, so the theorem is not correctly applied.